# How to set Timeout Interval with AFHTTPClient in AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

How to set time interval with AFHttpClient

```
   AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
    [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time out information is part of the `NSURLRequest` that you need to create and then feed to the client:

```
        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
    [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];


    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:10]; // <- 10 is the timeout interval

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [httpClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:req success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // DONE
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // FAILED
    }];
```