# AFNetworking : The Operation couldn't completed.(NSURLErrorDomain error -1004)

Tags: ios, error-handling, afnetworking-2

Some time, my server slow to response and I got this message in response, The Operation couldn't completed.(NSURLErrorDomain error -1004)

How to handle such errors?

P.S. I'm using AFNetworking for this.

Answer (score 0):

You may increase the time-out by overriding the get/post methods

Following is the example for get method

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                     parameters:(id)parameters
                        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:self.baseURL] absoluteString] parameters:parameters error:nil];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:ADD_YOUR_TIME_OUT_INTERVAL];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
    return operation;
}
```

P.S. I used this approach in the previous version of AFNetwork, by subclassing `AFHTTPClient`. I didn't test it in the new version's `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`.

This may be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22666837/1292441

Comment: I think, from AFNetworking-2.0 we should use, `AFHTTPSessionManager` if we're targeting iOS 7 and above. I am not sure about this, that how it'll affect to my app. I am looking for a natural solution. However thanks for your effort.